# Ascii convert to HEX

Tags: labview

I have a command file with this format:

```
31 01 FD 37 04
31 01 FD 37 05
31 01 FD 37 06
31 01 FD 37 07
```

This commands are in ASCII but i have to send my device same numbers just in HEX
so: *31 01 FD 37 04* **->** *31 01 FD 37 04*  **NOT(33 31 30 31 46 44 33 37 30 34 )**

Any idea?

Comment: This question is not totally clear so any of the answers below could be right. I would interpret this as the command file is a text file that could be edited in notepad and for each two characters command in the text file you need to send the actual HEX value out? If this is correct the answer by @CharlesB is correct.

Comment: This illustrates the problem of using the term 'in hex' or 'hex string' - to me there is no sense in which the bytes the questioner wants to send are 'in hex'. They're bytes whose value is given by the two-digit hex value in the text of the command file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly your file contains bytes whose values are 31, 01, FD, 37, 04 etc and you want to send the instrument the string "31 01 FD 37 04". You can do this conversion with a combination of String to Byte Array and Format Into String, for example:

[image]

If I've got your question the wrong way round then CharlesB's answer is correct.

Comment: I have strings and i want to send bytes.
My problem is solved, so thank you guys!

Answer (score 3):

There's a "Hexadecimal String To Number" VI in the palette String -> String/Number conversion. Loop 3 by 3 characters skipping space, and you'll get a nice array of numbers to send to your instrument.

Then, you can convert these numbers to a char array (see numeric conversion palette) and make a string out of it, ready to be written by VISA.

Comment: I'd actually remove all spaces from the file once you read it in.  It's easy to do by using the Search and Replace (All).

Answer (score 0):

You have the file with the correct ASCII characters, so you only need to open the file, read it's contents and forward it to a VISA resource:

[image: FileToVISA]